# laravel routes takes autometic ::index from controller. so index@index does not exist showing.(check images)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image]

I want to get the specific method of the controller, but it's not. By default, it's going to controller::index and showing me an error.

[image]

Please check all the images.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: You defined the routes as resources, you just have to specify the controller, ex: `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');` or replace `resource` with `get`,`post` etc

Comment: Why are you registering resource route twice ? I think registering it only one time is enough. remove the 2nd resource route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route as like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    Route::get('authors','authorController@index');
    Route::get('author/{id}','authorController@show');
});
```

**Or**

If you want to get it with **resource** then

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    Route::resource('authors','authorController');
});
```

For **resource** url will be.

`127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/authors` -> *get method* -> called **index** method

`127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/authors/1` -> *get method* -> called **show** method

Comment: Adding your 1st suggestion it's showing unexpected @

Comment: Oh, I missed apostrophe it'll be in string. check I've edited my answer

Comment: should like Route::get('authors','authorController@index'); Thanks man now its working actually i am new to PHP and laravel so